# Arithmetic operator cannot be applied to IntStream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a method that accepts an `ArrayList` of `int[]` arrays. If I call the method with an `ArrayList` of one `int[]` array, it should simply return the difference between the 2 values in the int[] array.
Using streaming, I've got

```
static int difference(ArrayList<int[]> stops) {
    return stops.stream().map(Arrays::stream).reduce((a, b) -> (a - b)).get();
}
```

Although I get a compiler error saying:

```
Operator '-' cannot be applied to 'java.util.stream.IntStream', 'java.util.stream.IntStream'
```

From my understanding, this method turns the List into a stream of `int[]` arrays, then streams each `int[]` array into an `IntStream`, until finally the `reduce()` method is called.

What I don't understand is that when I have the code like the following:

```
IntStream.of(1, 2).reduce((a, b) -> a - b));
```

I get no compiler errors.
So what I'm asking is, what is wrong with the first code that causes the compiler to throw that error? Because it appears to me that both reduce methods accept an IntStream.

Edit: The exercise I'm solving specifies each `int[]` array will hold exactly 2 elements. Once the difference is achieved between the two elements in the `int[]` array, it should be streamed to a final reduction to get the absolute value of the difference of the reduced `int`s from each `int[] array.

Comment: `stops.stream().map(Arrays::stream)` is stream of streams. Then you apply `a - b` on it, I think. You are subtracting two streams which makes no sense type-wise.

Comment: Beside the compiler problem: what are you trying to return when the input is a list? It seems that you want to subtract array elements, but you have multiple arrays. Or do you expect your list to be a singleton?

Comment: Replace `.map(Arrays::stream)` with `.flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)` But the reduction function `(a, b) -> a - b` is invalid, as it violates the [associativity requirement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity), `a - b - c ≠ a - (b - c)`.

Comment: The `difference(ArrayList<int[] stops>)` method must accept an ArrayList of several int arrays, then achieve an ultimate result from each of those reduced int arrays by reducing those elements once again. I now realize that the original `stops.stream()` produces a `stream<IntStream>` thanks to @Eran. So I plan using Eran's solution to reduce the elements in the stream of int arrays first, then reduce those corresponding elements once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stops.stream().map(Arrays::stream)` is a `Stream<IntStream>`, so when you are trying to reduce it, you can't apply `-` operator on two `IntStream` elements of it.

`IntStream.of(1, 2)` is an `IntStream`, so when you are trying to reduce it, you can apply `-` operator of two `int` elements of it.

It's not clear how you wish to reduce your `Stream<IntStream>` to a single `int`. You specified how you wish to reduce each of the `IntStream`s to an `int`, but how would you reduce the resulting `int`s to a single `int`?

You can reduce the `IntStream` elements of your `Stream<IntStream>` to obtain a `Stream<Integer>`:

```
Stream<Integer> si = stops.stream()
                          .map(ar -> Arrays.stream(ar)
                                           .reduce((a, b) -> (a - b))
                                           .getAsInt ());
```

Then you have to decide what you wish to do with the elements of that `Stream`.

Comment: `reduce((a, b) -> (a - b)` violates the contract, which requires an associative function. If you assume that the array always has exactly two elements, it may happen to work, but then, there’s no reason to use `Arrays.stream(ar) .reduce((a, b) -> (a - b)) .getAsInt()` instead of the straight-forward `ar[0] - ar[1]`…

Comment: @Holger agreed.

Answer (score 2):

I put together the following UT and tried to mimic what you tried to accomplish as well

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals;



public class IntStreamTest {

    int basicDifference() {
        return stops.stream().reduce(0, (a,b) -> a - b).intValue();
    }    

    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<Integer> stops = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

        int result = basicDifference(stops);

        assertEquals(result, -15);
    }


    int difference(List<int[]> stops) {
         return stops.stream().flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).reduce(0,(a,b) -> (a-b));
    }

    @Test
    public void given_a_list_of_two_arrays_when_the_list_is_reduced_the_difference_of_all_values_is_made() {
        int result = difference(Arrays.asList(new int[]{1,2,3}, new int[]{4,5,6}));

        assertEquals(-21, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void given_a_list_of_one_array_when_the_list_is_reduced_the_difference_of_all_values_is_made() {
        int result = difference(Arrays.asList(new int[]{1,2,3}));

        assertEquals(-6, result);
    }
}
```

So this works as I would expect it to work, starting from 0 and the difference of the rest of the integers. So in this case `0-1-2-3-4-5= -15` - in case of basicDifference() method. On the difference method, I used the input that was actually in the initial request, we can use flat map to have all the content in one place, especially as we reduce it twice. One can see in the UTs how it is used.